# Not showing all data from xml to listbox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to load data from the nodes in my xml file to get them to post in a listbox. 
Here is what my xml file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MovieData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
  </Movie>
</MovieData>
```

Here is what i am trying to do.

```
try
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(movieListXML);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/MovieData");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeList)
        {
            XmlNode movie = xn.SelectSingleNode("Movie");
            if (movie != null)
            {
                movieTypeListBox.Items.Add(movie["Name"].InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where my problem is ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate over your `Movie`s not your `MovieData`

```
try
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MovieData");
    foreach (XmlNode movie in node.SelectNodes("Movie"))
    {
        if (movie != null)
        {
            movieTypeListBox.Items.Add(movie["Name"].InnerText);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```